# Distribution of inverse of a random upper triangular invertible matrix over GF(2)

Tags: probability, abstract-algebra, galois-theory, random-matrices

I have a conjecture that I am trying to either prove or disprove, so far without much luck.

Suppose that $\mathbf{R}$ is a random square upper triangular matrix over $GF(2)$, which is invertible (i.e. the diagonal has all-ones, a necessary condition for invertibility clearly), and the off-diagonal elements are selected as Ber($\frac{1}{2}$) random variables.

What is the distribution of $\mathbf{R}^{-1}$ (where the inverse is over GF(2))? My conjecture is that $\mathbf{R}^{-1}$ is also a square random upper triangular matrix whose off-diagonal elements are all Ber($\frac{1}{2}$) (easy to prove) r.v.'s, AND **mutually independent** (difficult to prove).

For small examples such as for dimensions $n=2,3,4,5$ I can indeed check that the above is true. Any ideas on how to prove this?

Comment: Where you say "necessary condition", it should be "necessary and sufficient condition" (otherwise "i.e." would be wrong).

Comment: Yeah that is right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selecting the off-diagonal elements as independent Bernoulli variables with probability $\frac12$ leads to a uniform distribution over all invertible upper triangular $n\times n$ matrices. These are in bijection with their inverses, so taking the inverse leaves this uniform distribution invariant. Since the inverses are again uniformly distributed, their off-diagonal elements are again independent Bernoulli variables with probability $\frac12$.

Comment: I had the same exact thought. However this only proves for instance with three off diagonal elements of the inverse A,B, and C that P(A,B,C) = P(A)P(B)P(C) (please excuse the abuse in notation hope the meaning is clear). But how do I prove for instance that A and B are independent? I mean for mutual independence any subset of the random variables involved in the inverse should satisfy independence.

Comment: My worry is the following : We can find random variables A,B, and C which satisfy: $P(A \cap B) \neq P(A) P(B)$, $P(C \cap B) \neq P(C) P(B)$, $P(C \cap A) \neq P(C) P(A)$ 
 and $P(A \cap B \cap C) = P(A) P(B) P(C)$

Comment: Sorry never mind @joriki I figured it out. I had the problem done almost and do not know why I got confused by overthinking. Thanks anyways.